# prism4 :mouse events

Tags: prism

What is the best solution to implement mouse or load or select event in prism 4. I am adding double click event on dxgrid and looking for a best practice to implement this feature. 
for eg : mouse click, loaded, selected

Thanks,

Comment: Please be more specific. Are you using mvvm? Is it a WPF or silverlight application? Which version of prism are you using.

Comment: Based on the PRISM tag, I would thing you are using some sort of MVVM, but can you be more specific about your environment.

Answer (score 0):

You would typically use Behaviors for that. Behaviors map specific events of your View to commands in your ViewModel.